# Boosted Regression Trees: Zero discrimination and calibration scores

Tags: boosting, calibration

I am using boosted regression trees using the gbm() and dismo() packages. When I run my models I get values of zero for discrimination and calibration in the $cv.statistics

What would be the reason for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Found the answer through another source. Apparently Boosted Regression Trees don't calculate discrimination or calibration for non-categorical variables. Whereas for continuous variables deviance and correlation statistics are the measures of model fit.